# How to find a string in all tables without using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sometimes, I want to search a string to in all tables. But I find all the answers from Stackoverflow are using the stored procedure to do it. This is inconvenient because I do not want to create a store procedure in my sql server, and I just want to see where this string is existing in our database. So I provide below solution to help anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100) 
SET @SQL='' 

-- ------------------------------------------ 
-- Enter the string to be searched for here : 
-- 
SET @SearchString='Foo' 
-- ------------------------------------------ 

SELECT   @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),COUNT(*)) + '' matches in column ''+'''
         + C.name + '''+'' on table '' + ''' + SC.name + '.' + T.name + 
         ''' [Matches for '''+@SearchString+''':] FROM ' + 
         QUOTENAME(SC.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.name) + 
         ' LIKE ''%' + @SearchString + 
         '%'' HAVING COUNT(*)>0 UNION ALL ' +CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM     sys.columns C 
JOIN     sys.tables T 
ON       C.object_id=T.object_id 
JOIN     sys.schemas SC 
ON       SC.schema_id=T.schema_id 
JOIN     sys.types ST 
ON       C.user_type_id=ST.user_type_id 
JOIN     sys.types SYST 
ON       ST.system_type_id=SYST.user_type_id 
AND      ST.system_type_id=SYST.system_type_id 
WHERE    SYST.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar') 
ORDER BY T.name, C.name 

-- Strip off the last UNION ALL 
IF LEN(@SQL)>12 
  SELECT @SQL=LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)- 12) 

EXEC(@SQL) 

--PRINT @SQL
```

**How to use it:** 
Just relace the string you want to search with 'Foo' for @SearchString. Then you should be good to go.

P.S. If this helps you, please up vote this question and answer to let more developers see it.

Credit to this [post](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Searching%20all%20columns%20in%20all%20tables%20in%20a%20database.aspx)

Comment: It seems one could convert a stored procedure to an ad-hoc script by just removing the `CREATE ` and replacing the parameter declarations with DECLARE. Note that this aggregate string concatenation method can produce unexpected results. Better to use `FOR XML` or, in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2017, `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: "It seems one could convert a stored procedure to an ad-hoc script by just removing the CREATE and replacing the parameter declarations with DECLARE" You are right, I just want to provide this solution, so developers do not need to convert it again. This will save developer time.